# Matlab - Creating surface plot using three column vectors

Tags: matlab, geometry-surface

Say if I have three 1xn vectors representing n (X, Y, Z) value pairs, if I would like to generate a surface plot using these three vectors (with some smoothing), what would be the quickest way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by smoothing, Curve Fitting Toolbox might be a good bet.  This will allow you to do both interpolations, as well as smoothed fits to your data.

You can either use the interactive tool:

```
cftool
```

Or you can operate from the command line.  In this section I've fitted a surface, used the fit object to make a prediction for `z` with my first `x` and `y` values, and then plotted the fitted surface.  For reference, the documentation for `fit` can be found here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/curvefit/fit.html

*Example data:*

```
load franke
```

*Lowess Smoothing*

```
f = fit([x,y],z, 'lowess')
zPrediction = f(x(1), y(1))
plot(f)
```

*Piecewise Cubic Interpolant*

```
f = fit([x,y],z, 'cubicinterp')
zPrediction = f(x(1), y(1))
plot(f)
```

*User Defined Equation*

```
f = fit([x,y],z, 'a*x+b*exp(y)+c')
zPrediction = f(x(1), y(1))
plot(f)
```

Comment: Great idea and now I know what the non-parametric fitting is used for

Answer (score 2):

See `doc TriScatteredInterp`

```
F = TriScatteredInterp(X, Y, Z);
%the steps of tx and ty will allow you change smoothness
tx = min(X):max(X);
ty = mix(Y):max(Y);
[qx,qy] = meshgrid(tx,ty);
qz = F(qx,qy);
mesh(qx,qy,qz);
hold on;
plot3(x,y,z,'o');
```